# mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported

Tags: mount, rhel, nfs

NFS Mount is not working in my RHEL 7 AWS instance.

When I do a

```
mount -o nfsvers=3 10.10.11.10:/ndvp2 /root/mountme2/
```

I get the error:

```
mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

Can anyone point me where I am wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes,
NFS Utils was not installed on my AWS instance,

>yum install -y nfs-utils 
fixed it

Answer (score 21):

Check the nfs service is started or reboot the nfs service.

Comment: On Ubuntu you can check the status with `sudo systemctl status nfs-kernel-server`

Comment: This was it for me - on OpenSUSE, it's `systemctl status nfs-server.service` and `systemctl start nfs-server.service`.

Answer (score 6):

A precision which might be useful for the dump (like me): `systemctl status nfs-server.service` and `systemctl start nfs-server.service` must be executed on the **server**!

Answer (score 5):

If you're giving a specific protocol to connect with, also check to make sure your NFS server has that protocol enabled.

I got this error when trying to start up a Vagrant box, and my nfs server was running. It turns out that the command Vagrant uses is:

```
mount -o vers=3,udp,rw,actimeo=1 192.168.56.1:/dir/on/host /vagrant
```

Which specifically asks for UDP. My server was running but it was not configured to enable connecting over UDP. After consulting `/etc/nfs.conf`, I created `/etc/nfs.conf.d/10-enable-udp.conf` with the following contents to enable udp:

```
[nfsd]
udp=y
```

The name of the file doesn't matter, as long as it's in the `conf.d` directory and ends in `.conf`. Depending on your distribution it may be configured differently. You can directly edit `nfs.conf`, but using a `conf.d` file is more likely to preserve the changes after upgrading your system.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo systemctl status nfs-kernel-server`
In my case this package was not running and the issue was in /etc/exports file where i was having same IP address for two machines.
So i commented one ip address for the machine and restarted nf-kernel-server using
`sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server` and reload the machine.
It worked.

Answer (score 3):

Some additional data

If, like me, you've deleted a VM without shutting it down right you might also need to manually edit the file `/etc/exports` because NFS is trying to connect to it and fails but doesn't continue with the next, it just dies.

After that you can manually restart as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, a simple `reload` didn't suffice. I had to perform a full restart:

```
sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it didn't work correctly with version NFS 4.1.
So in Vargantfile in each place where is `type: 'nfs'` I added coma and `nfs_version: 4, nfs_udp: false`

Here is more detailing explanation [NFS](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs)

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping IP address of the server "ping " from client "ping , if you get reply then install nfs server on the host. Then edit /etc/exports file don't forget to add port along with IP address

Answer (score -2):

I got the solution: make an entry in nfs server /etc/nfsmount.conf  with `Defaultvers=3` .

There will `# Defaultvers=3`  just unhash it and then mount on nfs client.

Issue will be resolved!

Comment: its not solved for me and solved as the given above steps.